# Application crashes with access violation exception in mso20win32client.dll when use MAPI

Tags: outlook, office365, mapi

I have developed an application which uses MAPI to retrieve and process emails. When I configure office exchange server to retrieve emails using MAPI then it is crashing when i close the application. The crash is happening only when I have outlook365. With other version of outlook(2013 or earlier) then there is no crash but app hangs when we Uninitialize MAPI upon closing the application.

The crash dump point an access violation exception in mso20win32client.dll.

Here is the crash dump details :

{

```
   This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
   The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
   (4848.2ad4): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
    eax=00000000 ebx=00efeecc ecx=00000040 edx=00eff4f8 esi=00000000 edi=00000484
    eip=77342f3c esp=00efe734 ebp=00efe7a4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
    cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
    ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc:
    77342f3c c20c00          ret     0Ch
    0:000> .ecxr
    Unable to load image C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft 
    Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll, Win32 error 0n2
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mso20win32client.dll
    *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for mso20win32client.dll
    eax=00000000 ebx=6601b270 ecx=00000040 edx=00eff4f8 esi=1290db00 edi=0c23b8c0
    eip=5dfd97b4 esp=00eff4bc ebp=00eff4ec iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
    cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
    mso20win32client+0x197b4:
    5dfd97b4 8b4104          mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx+4] ds:002b:00000044=????????
```

The full dump I am not posting as it is very big.

Can someone please guide me on this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app quickly start up and shut down?

Comment: If you are talking about outlook app then there is no problem with it. The app which i developed, is crashing. And it crashes on manually closing the application.

Comment: Yes, but how much time elapses between calling MAPIInitialize and closing your app? There are known issues (being worked on) that result from shitting down the MAPI system when the common Office runtime is still initializing.

Comment: MAPIInitialize() takes place a lot longer before closing the app. We just do MAPIInitialize and then all the email processing using MAPI. Once everything is done, then we close the application. Sometimes immediately or sometimes after couple of mins.

Is there any workaround also?? Like wait for MAPIUnintialize before closing app or something ?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know then - I have seen similar crashes on shutdown before, but they were fixed in the later builds of Outlook 2016. Is your version up to date?

Comment: yeah.. nothing to fetch :-) It is already up to date

Comment: Can you create a crash dump using ProcDump.exe and upload it somewhere? I can try to make it available to MS.

Comment: I am not sure if I can share the dump.. but i can definitely share the dumb report. Please find the complete crash report here.                   
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/263102/application-crashes-with-access-violation-exceptio-1.html

Comment: A crash report is not really helpful.

Comment: Shall i share the crash dump with you?

Comment: Sure, send the ;link to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com. A few things you can check first - make sure the number of calls to MAPIInitialize and MAPIUninitialize are balanced.

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko... I checked the code and the MAPIInitialize and Uninitialize code is balanced. I checked the same with previous version of outlook and it is not crashing there.

After doing all that, i installed office365 again and not MAPIInitialize is failing all the time and now i cannot connect it to outlook anymore.

Comment: Does your app include the manifest? You need to tell Windows that Windows 10 is supported, otherwise it will be running in the compatibility mode, and MAPI does not like that.

Comment: Looks like the crash is happening when calling ExitProcess(0) in main application destructor.

Comment: I have seen that happen if the MAPI system is unloaded before it has a chance to fully initialize (asynchronously).

Comment: So how do we fully initialize(). In our app, we initialize MAPI upon starting the program. But the crash happens on closing the app.

Comment: How long does your app stay up? What is the exact Outlook version? Is it up to date?

Comment: my app stays up for couple of hour to few days also. I am using outlook365 v2101.
No more update to fetch.

Comment: When you look at the unmanaged call stack at the time of the crash, what do you see?

Comment: As of now i haven't find any breakthrough. So just wanted to try with older version of outlook365. Can you please let me know how can i rollback to older version of o365. Let's say o365 v2009 build 13231. Pls let me know you have idea about it.

Comment: I have the same problem with Outlook Professional Plus 2016. Did you find solution?